# send parameter to windows azure mobile server script in c# for Windows 8 Store app

Tags: sql, windows-8, windows-store-apps, azure-mobile-services

I modified the "Read" operation on my Windows Azure Mobile Services Preview table (named "Item") as follows:

Javascript:

```
function read(query, user, request) 
{

var howRead;

if(howRead == "unique")
{
    var sqlUnique = "SELECT DISTINCT ? FROM Item WHERE qProjectCode = ?";
    mssql.query(sqlUnique)
    request.execute();
}
else if (howRead == "column")
{
    var sqlColumn = "SELECT ? FROM Item WHERE qProjectCode = ?";
    mssql.query(sqlColumn)
    request.execute();
}
else if (howRead == "all")
{
   var sqlAll = "SELECT * FROM Item WHERE qProjectCode = ?";
    mssql.query(sqlAll)
    request.execute();
}

}
```

This simply species when I want a unique list of a single column's values returned, all items in a single column, or all columns, respectively, all while limiting the read to those records with a given project code.

Right now, this works in C#, but scans the entire table (with other project codes) and always returns all columns.  This is inherently inefficient.

c#

```
var client = new MobileServiceClient("[https path", "[key]");

var table = client.GetTable<Item>();

var query1 = table.Where(w => w.QProjectCode == qgv.projCode && w.QRecord == (int)lbRecord.Items[uStartRecordIndex]);

var query1Enum = await query1.ToEnumerableAsync();

foreach (var i in query1Enum)
     {
     // process data
     }
```

How do I alter the c# code to deal with the Javascript code?  Feel free to critique the overall approach, since I am not a great programmer and can always use advice!

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

A few things:

- In your server code, the `mssql` calls are not doing anything (useful). If you want to get their results, you need to pass a callback (the call is asynchronous) to it.
- Most of your scenarios can be accomplished at the client side. The only for which you'll need server code is the one with the `DISTINCT` modifier.
- For that scenario, you'll need to pass a custom parameter to the server script. You can use the `WithParameters` method in the `MobileServiceTableQuery<T>` object to define parameters to pass to the service.

Assuming this data class:

```
public class Item
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Other { get; set; }
    public string ProjectCode { get; set; }
}
```

The code below can be used to accomplish the scenarios 2 and 3 at the client side only (no script needed at the server side). The other one will need some script, which I'll cover later.

```
Task<IEnumerable<string>> ReadingByColumn(IMobileServiceTable<Item> table, string projectCode)
{
    return table
        .Where(i => i.ProjectCode == projectCode)
        .Select(i => i.Name)
        .ToEnumerableAsync();
}

Task<IEnumerable<Item>> ReadingAll(IMobileServiceTable<Item> table, string projectCode)
{
    return table.Where(i => i.ProjectCode == projectCode).ToEnumerableAsync();
}

Task<IEnumerable<string>> ReadingByColumnUnique(IMobileServiceTable<Item> table, string projectCode)
{
    var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        { "howRead", "unique" },
        { "projectCode", projectCode },
        { "column", "Name" },
    };
    return table
        .Select(i => i.Name)
        .WithParameters(dict)
        .ToEnumerableAsync();
}
```

Now, to support the last method (which takes the parameters, we'll need to do this on the server script:

```
function read(query, user, request) 
{
    var howRead = request.parameters.howRead;
    if (howRead) {
        if (howRead === 'unique') {
            var column = request.parameters.column; // WARNING: CHECK FOR SQL INJECTION HERE!!! DO NOT USE THIS IN PRODUCTION!!!
            var sqlUnique = 'SELECT DISTINCT ' + column + ' FROM Item WHERE ProjectCode = ?';
            mssql.query(sqlUnique, [request.parameters.projectCode], {
                success: function(distinctColumns) {
                    var results = distinctColumns.map(function(item) {
                        var result = [];
                        result[column] = item; // mapping to the object shape
                        return result;
                    });

                    request.respond(statusCodes.OK, results);
                }
            });
        } else {
            request.respond(statusCodes.BAD_REQUEST, {error: 'Script does not support option ' + howRead});
        }
    } else {
        // no server-side action needed
        request.execute();
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow ... wonderful stuff.  I followed your instructions and the ReadingAll and ReadingColumn routines work great.  !Huge! time savings over my initial approach.  So thanks a lot.  I could not get the ReadingByColumnUnique routine to work, and it breaks the other two routines (I get internal server errors every time for all three routines if I change the server script to your code).  I played around with it alot and my best guess (keeping in mind I know very little) is that the variable handoff and/or logic is not right.  Could be something completely different.  Any followup thoughts?

Comment: Debugging server scripts at this point isn't a very easy thing to do. What I usually end up doing is writing a bunch of `console.log` statements throughout the script to pinpoint where the error is.